# Drop down in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I am trying to select values from a drop down in my application. Drop down is getting identified as WebEdit in UFT.

Here is the line of code:

```
Browser().page().WebEdit("html tag:=INPUT","name:=WebEdit").Set "Add Document"
```

Add Document is a value in dropdown. Apart from "Add document" value, there are more values in drop down. please suggest how can i select those values one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the properties of the object?  Generally you could use `GetROProperty("items")` from a `WebList` object to return all the values and then iterate over them.  But a `WebEdit` is just supposed to be a textbox...  Can you give more information about the object you are trying to interact with?

Answer (score 0):

it should be WebList Object in Web application if it's a Dropdown.

I guess it's a Text Box Only in which if you click, multiple suggestion come like MakeMyTrip .

if it's the case you can use two approach.

```
1) Browser().page().WebEdit("html tag:=INPUT","name:=WebEdit").Set "SomeValue"
or
2) Browser().page().WebEdit("html tag:=INPUT","name:=WebEdit").Set "Someval"
  ' Then There will be Multiple Sujjestions, Which are nothing but WebElement.
  ' just click that WebElement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use descriptive programming to select values.
That way UFT won't select it as textbox implicitly.
Let me know if you are still facing issues.

Comment: Browser("<>").Page("<>").  WebList("micclass:=WebList","name:=<>").Select "<value>"

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I guess the drop down you mentioned should be a dynamic one, Meaning a drop down will appear when you type words in that `WebEdit` column.

If so, my suggestion is that you can write a function to locate object's location (i.e. `x`,`y` property), and simulate mouse click the object. Now the object has been activated and you can type words. Use `SendKey` method to type some keywords you want to select, and use `SendKey` to press `Enter` to select it.

It's an ugly solution but sometimes it helps...